# Why the $M$ for Thom spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, ho.history-overview, terminology

I've heard $E$ is for entire space, $B$ is for base space, so what is $M$ for?

Comment: No clue, manifold?

Comment: I reckon E is not for "entire space", but for "étalé space"
(étalé means "spread out").

Comment: Thom uses notation such as $M(SO(n))$ for the Thom space in his original papers, e.g., Quelques propriétés globales des variétés différentiables. 
Comment. Math. Helv. 28, (1954). 17–86.  So presumably he is responsible for that notation.  

Comment: $T$ was already taken for tangent bundle, so $M$ is a pretty good 2nd fiddle. 

Comment: It seems that the earliest use is in Thom's paper: http://archive.numdam.org/article/SB_1951-1954__2__271_0.pdf