What does the M stand for in the cobordism theories MO, MSL and MU?
Guess: Is it because it is related the mapping cylinder of some map?

I have not (yet) found an authoritive source, but the natural interpretation is that M stands for "manifold"

I would guess the first occurence of the $M$ for the Thom space of a vector bundle is the 1954 article of Thom "quelques ...". (Some “global” properties of
differentiable manifolds). He doesn't mention any meaning to $M$.

https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

I just notice now that the M-question was also asked here in 2012, with similar comments but without an answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/93296/11260

M for manifold seems to make sense, but Thom was french and maybe would have preferred V for varieté.

The $M$ notation in a cobordism spectrum is derived from the $M$ notation for a Thom space (since the cobordism spectrum is built up out of the Thom spaces). Here is the paragraph where the $M$ notation is first introduced, where Thom defines the Thom space $M(G)$ of a subgroup $G$ of the orthogonal group $O(k)$. :

Définition. On appellera complexe associé au sous-groupe $G$ de $O(k)$,
l'espace dénoté $M(G)$ obtenu à partir de $A_G$ par identification en un
point a de son bord $E_G$ ; $M(G)$ est, si l'on veut, la compactification
d'Alexandroff de l'espace fibré en boules ouvertes $A'_G$.

The quotation is from section II.2 of Thom's 1954 thesis, "Quelques propriétés globales des variétés différentiables."
Perhaps Thom chose the symbol $M$ simply because it was just a convenient symbol that didn't already mean something else in that context. I see only one hint about why else he might have chosen the letter $M$. Here is the text immediately following the definition quoted above:

Cohomologie de $M(G)$. La cohomologie $H^r(M(G))$ s'identifie, pour tout $r >0$, à la cohomologie à supports compacts $H^r_K(M(G))$, ou encore,
à la cohomologie relative $H^r(A_G,E_G)$. Or, on a l'isomorphisme classique de la théorie des espaces fibrés en boules ouvertes (Cf. [26]): $\phi_G^*: H^{r-k}(B_G) \rightarrow H^r_K(A^{'}_G) \cong H^r(M(G))$
les coefficients étant pris dans le groupe $Z_2$ en général, dans $Z$ si l'espace
fibré $E_G$ est orientable ($G$ connexe). La cohomologie $H^*(M(G))$ s'obtient donc, pour les dimensions $r >0$, en majorant de k unités la graduation de la cohomologie $H^*(B_G)$ de l'espace classifiant $B_G$.

As Thom writes, the cohomology of the Thom space $M(G)$ agrees with the cohomology of the classifying space $B_G$ of $G$-bundles but with the grading degrees shifting by increasing them ("en majorant"). This isomorphism in cohomology is the famous Thom isomorphism. Perhaps the letter $M$ stands for majorant, i.e., increasing, which is what $M(G)$ looks like in cohomology in comparison to $B_G$: the same thing but with all grading degrees increased.
But this is only a bit of speculation, prompted by the observation that "majorant" is the only word in that section of Thom's paper which begins with the letter M.
